# PHP/MySQL Display all data fields including images

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a site that needs to display inventory data. I am using these fields in my table (Product_Name, Product_Type, Product_Price, Product_Image). I am able to get all of this info uploaded via PHP (I am storing the images in a folder and not in the database via BLOB). I can get it to display the first 3 columns (Name, Type, Price). I can't get it to display the image. I have read that I cannot display binary data as well as other field types because of the header declaration. I know how to do the thumbnail with PHP. I want the thumbnail to be clickable with a lightbox type deal showing the full size image.

I had a screenshot to show what I am trying to do, but I am not able to because I am new to this site.

I have found numerous tuts on how to upload files, how to display images from either a folder or a BLOB, but I have not found an answer to what I am trying to do.

Is it even possible through PHP to do a SELECT * from table and display all fields in a table, including a thumbnail which is clickable to display full size image.

I am hoping that someone can point me in the right direction, either a tutorial or someone who could show me some sample code.

Thanks!

Comment: You may post a link to the screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you storing the image info in your database? A link? Something else? To display the image, output the link location via MySQL and output it on the page. You'll need to use a lightbox library to display it in a lightbox pop-up window.

ie...

in your table you have:

```
images/myimage.jpg
```

On your page use something like:

```
<?php
echo "<img src='$image' alt='something' /> ";
?>
```

You'll need to define `$image` somewhere after you connect to you db.

Comment: I prefer to store images in the file system, since everything I read says do not BLOB because of bloating the database. I can get it to display just the actual image. It seems that with the header declaration does not allow me to display the other fields (varchar) and the image field.

Comment: so, I can echo out the first 3 varchar columns like I normally do. then I add the echo line from above "img src" where I define $image in my conn info as the field in the database that holds the path?

Comment: Sorry, I'm just not understanding what you're trying to do. What does the `header declaration` have to do with this?

Comment: `where I define $image in my conn info as the field in the database that holds the path?` yes

Comment: I read that if you are serving up binary data (images), you have to have a header declaration and that you aren't supposed to echo anything before or after it. So, $image should = /images or do I have to explicitly state the image file name?

Comment: I think you're over complicating  it. In your database you'll store the path. i.e. `uploads/image1.jpg`. Then when you query the database, you'll pull the related path and store it as a variable `$image`. The variable `$image` will now contain the path `uploads/image1.jpg`. Then, build an `<img>` tag as shown in my example.

Comment: `if you are serving up binary data (images)` you're not. that might be true if the image were stored as a BLOB.

Comment: Excellent Paul. That answers my question, and yes, I am sure that i over complicated it.

Comment: Sorry, upvoting is not available to me because I am new. I did click that it was useful.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're generating an HTML page (Which you should be doing!), just store the path to the image in the database, and generate an `<img>` tag which has a `src=` attribute of the path from the database.

### Example output:

Assuming you got one result (to simplify), and you stored it in a variabled called `$reuslt`:

```
<?php

    /**
     * @var array $result
     * Received from Database, mockup.
     */
    $result = array(
        "name"  => "Name",
        "type"  => "Type",
        "price" => "Price",
        "image" => "path/to/image.png"
    );

    foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
        $$key = $value;
    }


    $html = <<<EOH
<ul>
    <li>Name: $name</li>
    <li>Type: $type</li>
    <li>Price: $price</li>
    <li>Image: <img src="$image"></li>
</ul>
EOH;

    echo $html;
```

Comment: I understand that part. The part that I am having difficulty understanding is how do I know what the path to the photo is? For example, I have an HTML form that pushes Product_Name, Product_Type, Product_Size, and Product_Image to my upload.php. How can I be sure that the file that is uploaded (Product_Image) with the other fields  will display with that record? So, if I enter the following into my form: Product_Name: Scabos, Product_Type: Travertine, Product_Size: 18x18, and upload scabos.jpg  and upload, how do I display to make sure that scabos.jpg is in the row with the right other fields?

Comment: So you're basically asking how to handle uploaded files. Happy reading: http://il.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php

Comment: No, I have no issues getting things uploaded. The question is how to display the 3 varchar columns, and then have the thumbnail of the corresponding image in a 4th column. I can handle the thumbnail and whatever lightbox effect for the full size image.

Comment: I think I understand now that I see your last edit to your sample code. Where is $html defined?  Other than that I do understand!!!

Comment: Is the path to the image as defined in the result array dynamically generated during the file upload process?

Comment: $html is defined where you see it defined (starting on `$html = <<<EOH`) it's an alternative syntax for defining strings (easy with multiline strings with quotes). See http://il.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Comment: You need to save the path to the database after the upload is successful.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I am reading over the links that you supplied. I am now getting a better idea of what I need to do. Thanks!